# Does copyright law apply if I download films in Iran?

Tags: copyright

I live at Iran. I would like to know if downloading films, like Hollywood films, via internet is illegal, if I don't pay money to the owner?

I'm asking because I read [this](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/vb7k8j/its-illegal-to-pirate-films-in-iran-unless-youre-the-government):

> Iran's copyright law does not protect authors outside of Iran either.
> While Iran is a member of the World Intellectual Property Organisation
> (WIPO), a specialized United Nations agency tasked with promoting the
> protection of global intellectual property, it has never signed the
> WIPO copyright treaty, nor any other international copyright
> agreements that would make infringing copyrights of foreigners
> unlawful.

If downloading is legal under Iranian law, is it illegal under international law, or perhaps under spiritual or religious law?

Thanks.

Comment: *"and does it related to international low, or the copy right law for one Hollywood films is one permission of producer of films to not be seen for every one, and spiritual!?"* I assume you used Google Translate to do this post, but this sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: Google is fine, maybe i must use more it, now edited, maybe become better.

Comment: We can't answer questions about spiritual law here; I suggest taking it to SE.Islam.

Comment: This kind of question is some partly because of the religion failure between Iranian people which created many ethical questions, i want know does it is illegal based of international law and if possible considering more ethical aspects.

Comment: The article Bay‘ al-ḥuqūq al-mujarradah by Muhammad Taqi Usmani published in *Buḥūth fī qaḍāya fiqhīyah mu‘āṣirah* purportedly presents the arguments consistent with Shari\`ah.

Answer (score 1):

### Iran is **not** a member of the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) on copyright

As such, it does not respect other countries' copyrights, and vice-versa.

Notwithstanding, domestic Iranian [law](https://wayback.archive-it.org/10611/20161115114752/http://portal.unesco.org/culture/en/files/30380/11424169773ir_copyright_1970_en.pdf/ir_copyright_1970_en.pdf) protects “authors” and appears to make no distinction between international and domestic authors. As such, it would appear to be illegal.

Comment: So you say the lack of membership could cover internal law, and does it works in law logical algorithms?

Comment: @SoheilPaper I have no idea what your comment means